# IIs Express, Local IIS: Web Config error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type add with unique key attribute Path set to '*'

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express, iis-8

I am trying to run my asp.net app.When I run this I am getting this error. I am using Local iis Web server. Could somebody please advice me.

Comment: Open up `web.config` and add `<remove>` tags before all your `<add>` tags to make sure duplicate items from parent levels are removed before adding your own. You do need to study IIS/ASP.NET configuration hierarchy further and understand why such errors happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message mentions a duplicate record, check the web.config for identical definitions.

If there are no duplicates, check the rules in tracing module at all application, site, and server levels in IIS express, make sure there are no conflicting rules.

If the issue still persists, add the line below into web.config. It will remove all existing rules to prevent duplication.

```
<remove path="*" />
```